Spark-Hudi: Unable to perform Hard delete using Pyspark on HUDI table from AWS Glue
I am trying to perform a hard delete operation on a HUDI table, but unable to delete the data in the table. My setup is pretty straightforward I use a normal glue Job to create the hudi tables and use Glue Data Catalog.
I tried the following approaches,

EmptyHoodieRecordPayload:-

hudiOptions={
"hoodie.datasource.write.table.type": "COPY_ON_WRITE",
"hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": "uid, cust_id",
"hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": "insert_timestamp",
"hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field": "date",
"hoodie.table.name": "test_table"}

DF.write.format('org.apache.hudi') \
    .option('hoodie.datasource.write.operation', delete') \
    .option('hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class', 'org.apache.hudi.common.model.EmptyHoodieRecordPayload') \
    .options(**hudiOptions) \
    .mode('append') \
    .save(path)


Normal delete write operations:

DF.write.format('org.apache.hudi') \
    .option('hoodie.datasource.write.operation', delete') \
    .options(**hudiOptions) \
    .mode('append') \
    .save(path)


Normal spark SQL:
spark.sql("DELETE FROM hudi_cow_nonpcf_tbl WHERE uuid = 1")
with the following configurations,

--conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' 
--conf 'spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog' 
--conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension' 
--conf 'spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false' 

Environment Description:
Glue : 4.0
Hudi version : 0.12.1
Spark version : 3.3
python : 3
Storage (HDFS/S3/GCS..) : S3
All three approaches weren't able to delete the data and also didn't throw any errors.
If any one who used similar setup, kindly help me out.

For anyone who is facing the same issue, it is resolved for me by using the Hudi 0.14.0-spark 3.3 bundle jar.I believe something is wrong with the glue-based Hudi, and it is better to always provide the jars than using the native version.
